# Good equivalent of "zsh/bash + iTerm2 for Windows 10/11

Tags: windows-10, ssh, terminal-emulator, bash

**OS**: Windows 10 Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045

I moved from MacOS to Windows 10. I'm missing a lot the shells I had there (`bash` and `zsh`) as well as the terminal emulator (iTerm2). I'm looking for a good substitute, which allows me to connect to remote Linux servers in SSH. I'm asking a single question, instead of one for the shell and one for the terminal, because it looks like on Windows some apps ship both a terminal **and** a terminal. Anyway, answers pointing to a combination of two different apps X and Y are fine, as long as terminal X can run shell Y.

**Strict requirements**

- easy to install (no compilation from source!)
- free, preferably open source
- the shell must be `bash` or `zsh`, with the usual features (tab completion, reverse-i search, etc.)
- SSH connection to remote servers, file transfer, possibility to add a private SSH key so that I don't need to enter my password every time I connect to the remote server
- tabs
- copy/paste text using mouse, inside the terminal and from the terminal to the Windows clipboard
- compatible with Windows 10 and Windows 11

**Nice to have**

- fast rendering (I used Hyper years ago, and )
- configure the prompt using Oh-my-zsh or something similar
- splits windows, tab tearout
- being able to copy text from a tmux session on the remote server, to the Windows clipboard. This would actually be a requirement, but I had a hard time finding a terminal which allowed this even on MacOS (basically, the only one was iTerm 2), so I decided to put it as a nice to have.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Windows comes with WSL/WSL2 environment so you have a real Linux with file-system access to Windows files.

Comment: Any particular reason for Windows 10 and not 11? as mentioned by @Robert above, WSL2 is the best way to utilize it.

Comment: @Lockszmith WSL2 works fine with Windows 10 and 11, so no need to use 11.

Comment: Sorry about that, [you are correct](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-install-wsl2-windows-10) @Robert, I rememberd incorrectly, WSL2 was a major upgrade, and was introduced after a Windows 10 and 11 major upgrade (21H1 and 21H2). Apologies... it has been over 2 years now since that point - getting old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use Windows Terminal + GitBash, or setup WSL2 option on Windows. In 1 variant - you will work in windows core, in 2 - in ubuntu linux os.

[image: This is my terminal on GitBash]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Like CygWin?

https://www.cygwin.com/

And as far as tabbed terminal, W11 does this native now, and openssh built in, makes tabbed ssh sessions seamless.

Possibly tabby if stuck in W10 world. https://tabby.sh/

You may find some alternatives in the WSL as well, think of it like a quasi VM / Reverse Wine. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about

Comment: I second this, these are excellent options. I would add that Tabby is probably a better option even in Windows 11, with its SSH plugin with support for tunneling and SCP file transfer, and it's profile/config synchronization options.